# Store a edited dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, import

I am importing data from an excel file (.xls) as a DataFrame. Once the DataFrame has been imported, I manipulate it, modifying several fields and columns. For the following steps, I would like to use the modified DataFrame and not work from the beginning with the excel file.

How could I store the DataFrame, so that each time I call the script, it does not import the excel file from scratch but work with the already imported and modified DataFrame?

Comment: You can pickle the DataFrame https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle.html. This means you seriealize the data and store it as a file. You can then read the pickled df in using this method https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_pickle.html.

Comment: Is it very important that the output be excel format? You can export the newly formatted data into a CSV with functionality built into the python environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pandas.DataFrame` class has a method `.to_pickle()` that you can use. This will serialize the object and store it keeping its attributes as you want (dtypes, etc.).

Then you can read the file with `pandas.read_pickle()`.